# How to dynamic allocate a two dimensional array

Tags: c, multidimensional-array

I would like to make a two dimensional array in C.

For example, I make an int type variable named place like this:

```
int *place;
```

I have a game, which have variables like rows, and columns. 
I would like my place variable to be a two dimensional array, with dynamic allocation of its rows and columns (for the max size of the array), which would look like this in the "normal" declaration:

```
place[rows][columns];
```

but I don't know how to do it with the dynamic allocation.

I would do it like this for one-dimensional arrays:

```
place = (int*) malloc (levels * sizeof(int));
```

but I don't know how to do this with 2D arrays.

**Edit:**

How I can rewrite this for char instead of int?

I have tried to just overwrite the ints with chars, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Can you show what you tried to use it for `char`s and tell how it didn't work? All answers work independent of the base type, you just have to replace the type name in the appropriate places.

Comment: I have made a variable like this:
char place;

then:
(*place)[columns] = malloc(rows * sizeof *place);

but it doesn't works, say conflicting types for place

Comment: No, the syntax (admittedly not a good syntax, IMO) is `char (*place)[columns];` to declare `place` as a pointer to arrays of `columns` `char`s, a `char (*)[columns]`. You can as usual initialise immediately upon declaration, `char (*place)[columns] = malloc(rows * sizeof *place);`.

Comment: I tried it, now it is say, that initializer element is not a constant.
I have tried to make columns and rows constants but it isn't good neither.

Comment: If it complains that the initialiser is not constant, that means your object has static storage duration. That changes things. a) static objects need constant expressions for initialisers, b) static objects can't have variably modified types. If `columns` can be a constant expression, you can still declare `char (*place)[columns];`, and 1. if it is at file scope, `malloc` in `main`, 2. if it has function scope, have a static guard variable and `malloc` when the function is first called. If both, `rows` and `columns` can be constant expressions, use `char place[rows][columns];`.

Comment: Do you need `place` to have static storage duration? (For a pointer, that is rather pointless.)

Comment: I have some function which use the same variables. I don't exactly know that how can I pass them between fuctions, because some of these functions don't have return value.

Comment: When one of these functions calls another, it can without problem pass the array as an argument if it received it itself as one. Declare it in the top-level caller, and pass it as an argument to what functions need the array.

Answer (score 10):

Let `place` be a pointer to arrays,

```
int (*place)[columns] = malloc(rows * sizeof *place);
```

That gives you a contiguous block of memory (good for locality) that you can simply access with

```
place[i][j] = whatever;
```

Comment: +1 This is one of the examples where parenthesizing `*place` would be of great help visually.

Comment: But with this solution, how I can malloc the columns too? Won't it only malloc the rows? I mean, if I would like to change the rows and columns, on every level of my game, then how can I change the rows' and columns' value with it?

Comment: @AshRj `place` is declared as an `int (*)[columns]`, a pointer to an array of `columns` `int`s. Then you allocate memory for `rows` objects of the type `place` points to.

Comment: @user590898 `place` then points to an array (of `columns` integers), so `sizeof *place == columns * sizeof(int)`, thus you overall allocate `rows*columns*sizeof(int)` bytes.

Comment: @DanielFischer If i do *place, then will i access place[0][0] ?

Comment: If so then why is sizeof(*place) not equal to sizeof(int) ?

Comment: @AshRj No, `*place` will be `place[0]`, an array of `columns` `int`. `**place` will get you to `place[0][0]`.

Comment: @DanielFischer Ahh.. Now its all good :) Thanks for explaining. And i must say, that one line of code looks awesome ..

Answer (score 0):

You need to do the following to allocate arr[x][y] of type int dynamically:

```
 int i = 0;
 int **arr = (int**)calloc(x, sizeof(int*));
 for(i = 0; i < x; i++)
      arr[i] = (int *) calloc(y, sizeof(int));
```

The idea is to first create a one dimensional array of pointers, and then, for each array entry, create another one dimensional array.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a single 1d array as a 2d array by some smart indexing :

Allocate memory :

```
place = (int*) malloc(rows * columns * sizeof(int));
```

To access `place[i][j]`, use i and j as :

```
place[ i*columns + j] = value ;
```