# Confusion: Dynamic Allocation of 2D array, C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, sizeof

I yesterday came across a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13659041/how-can-i-dynamic-allocate-a-two-dimensional-array/) on SO, that wanted to dynamically allocate a 2-D array in C.

One of the answers was to allocate it this way:

`int (*place)[columns] = malloc(rows * sizeof *place);`

This apart from being beautiful, brought a question to my head. The question goes below:

Following is the code in which i allocate a 4x4

```
    int (*arr)[4] = (int (*)[4]) malloc(4 * sizeof *arr);
    printf("%d\n", sizeof arr);                 //Dynamic 2-D array by above method
    
    int **arr1 = (int**) malloc(4 * sizeof(int*));
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            arr1[i] = (int *) malloc(sizeof(double));
    printf("%d\n", sizeof arr1);                          //Usual dynamic 2-D array

    int *arr2 = (int*) malloc(4 * sizeof(int));
    printf("%d\n", sizeof arr2);                          //Dynamic 1-D array
```

The usual output is:

```
4
4
4
```

However, if i try to print `sizeof *arr`, `sizeof *arr1` and `sizeof *arr2`, the output is:

```
16
4
4
```

I don't understand why this is happening. Any idea why the output for `sizeof *arr` is `16`? How is the memory being being allocated in the first case?

Also, when i try to print the address of `arr` and `*arr`, both the printed values are same. `*arr` means "value at" `arr`. So does that mean arr stores its own address, i.e., it is pointing to itself (which i don't think is possible)? Am slightly confused. Any idea where am I going wrong?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: address of arr and *arr is the same because address of first element in your array is the same as address of beginning of first row. Nothing weired in that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> However, if I try to print `sizeof *arr`, `sizeof *arr1` and `sizeof *arr2`, I get `16`, `4`, and `4`.

where:

```
int (*arr)[4];
int **arr1;
int *arr2;
```

You must be working on a 32-bit machine, not a 64-bit machine.

The type of `arr` is 'pointer to an array of 4 `int`'.  When you dereference it, you get an 'array of 4 `int`'.  When passed to `sizeof`, the array is of size 16 (`4 * sizeof(int)`).  Most of the time, when you reference an array, the type is adjusted to 'pointer to zeroth element of the array', but `sizeof()` is the primary exception to that rule; it sees an array as an array and returns the size of the whole array.

The type of `arr1` is 'pointer to pointer to `int`'.  When you dereference it, you get a 'pointer to `int`'.  When passed to `sizeof`, the pointer is of size 4 (`sizeof(int *)`).

The type of `arr2` is 'pointer to `int`'.  When you dereference it, you get an `int`.  When passed to `sizeof`, the `int` is of size 4.

---

> Okay! I get most of it. But ... why isn't the output 16 when I do `sizeof arr2`?

As James noted in his comment:

> because `sizeof(arr2)` reduces to `sizeof(int*)` which on a 32-bit machine is 4.

That is, `arr2` is a pointer; the size of a pointer is 4 on a 32-bit machine.

> Also, arr is a 'pointer to an array of 4 int', i.e., a single pointer. Then how do I get a 4×4 matrix.

You can use either of these:

```
int mat1[4][4];
int (*mat2)[4][4];
```

The first is a straight-forward 4×4 matrix.  The result of `sizeof(mat1)` will be 64 on a 32-bit machine (and most 64-bit machines, as it happens).

The second is a pointer to a 4×4 matrix of `int`.  The result of `sizeof(mat2)` will be 4 on a 32-bit machine; `mat2` is a pointer (to a 4×4 matrix of `int`), so it is of size 4, the same as every other object pointer (and, in practice, the same size as every function pointer, though the C standard does not guarantee that function pointers and object pointers are the same size; POSIX does guarantee that, though).

The result of `sizeof(*mat2)` is the size of the object that `mat2` points at, which is a 4×4 matrix of `int`, so the size is 64 again.

Comment: Okay! I get most of it. But you say: " Most of the time, when you reference an array, the type is adjusted to 'pointer to zeroth element of the array', but sizeof() is the primary exception to that rule". Then why isn't the output `16` when i do a `sizeof arr2`?

Comment: @shrey347 because `sizeof(arr2)` reduces to `sizeof(int*)` which on a 32-bit machine is 4

Comment: Also, `arr` is a 'pointer to an array of 4 `int`', i.e., a single pointer. Then how do i get a 4x4 matrix. Sorry if this seems silly!!

Comment: @shrey347: `arr` is a pointer to the first element of a 4x4 array of arrays. However, given a pointer to the first element of an array, you don't know (and cannot find out) how big the array is.

Answer (score 1):

In a 32 bit system it needs 4 bytes or 32 bit to identify each memory address uniquely. A pointer is nothing just the holder of the address. so it takes 4 byte. In the first case arr is an array of pointer of length 4. so it takes 4*4 =16 bytes. in the other two case arr1 and arr2 are just a single pointer. so they take 4 bytes.