# Runtime Error with Two Dimensional Arrays

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array, runtime, runtime-error

Trying to solve [this problem](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/find-point) from Hackerrank. The problem itself is conceptually simple, basically finding the coordinates of a point by a simple arithmetic operation.

But the code requires us to print out multiple solutions after taking all the inputs, for which I am using a two-dimensional nx2 array. n is taken as the input from the user. Unfortunately, whenever n>=3, the hackerrank interface just does not give any output at all and I get wrong solutions. I tried to run the same code in my local IDE (CodeBlock for windows). There, when n>=3, the execution stops as the .exe file encounters some runtime error. So is it impossible to use a big matrix in those interfaces?

```
int main() {
    unsigned int i=0, n;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    int **array=malloc(2*sizeof(int*));
    for(;i<2;i++) *(array+i)=malloc(n*sizeof(int));                  

    for(i=0;i<n;i++){/*Takes input via scanf*/
                     /* Calculate and store the result in **(array+i), *(*(array+i)+1))*/
                    }

    for(i=0;i<n;i++) printf("%d %d\n", **(array+i), *(*(array+i)+1));
/*Prints the outputs. This is where the runtime error happens*/


    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: "the code requires us to print out multiple solutions after taking all the inputs" — no it doesn't. You can print out the results for each set of coordinates as they are read in. Your code would be *much* more readable if you replaced `*(*(array+i)+1))` with something sensible like `array[i][1]`

Comment: Thanks, but the hackerrank interface here wants to accept all the inputs first, then I can print the output. So I have to store them either in a matrix, or two different arrays. Also, I am not conceptually clear whether *(*(array+i)+1)) corresponds to array[i][1] or array[1][i].

Comment: (1) No, it really doesn't. `scanf("%d %d %d %d", &x0, &y0, &x1, &y1); printf("%d %d\n", x1*2-x0, y1*2-y0);` works just fine. (2) `*(*(array+i)+1))` == `array[i][1]` (hence the segmentation errors you mentioned)

Comment: Thanks, I tried your suggestion of (1) and it did work. It does not require any array to store anything. Anyway, is it possible for you to tell me how to properly use the matrix with pointer to pointer data type? Is there a way to avoid the segmentation error that occurs only with n>3? May be the answer is too comprehensive to fit, but some reference where I can study will be great.

Comment: There are already lots of good answers about dynamic allocation in C. Here'e one example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13659064/1679849

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding please follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*

Comment: in general, 1) when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions, always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful.  2) when calling any of the heap memory allocation functions (malloc, calloc, realloc), always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.